# How can I display different boxplots side by side in the same figure (matlab)?

Tags: matlab, boxplot

I have four different vectors in my data. I want to create four different `boxplots` for each one of them and display them all in the same figure,side by side so I can compare them. Is that possible ? `Subplot` is not actually what would fit in this case and I have also tried `hold on` but that doesn't work either (at least the way I do it). I am quite new in Matlab so could you please help me figure this out ?

Thanks

```
first_plot=100*scores./counts; 
second_plot=100*Fscores./Fcounts; 
third_plot=100*Gscores./Gcounts; 
fourth_plot=100*Pscores./Pcounts;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

first put your data in one matrix:

```
F(:,1) = a;
F(:,2) = b;
...
boxplot(F(:,1:2));xlabel('SA - MP')
```

it becomes something like the following picture:

[image]

Comment: great -exactly what I wanted ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: do not forget to choose this answer as best answer. ;)